# onMeasure not getting called in my custom viewgroup android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewgroup

Im having two custom `viewgroups`, `superViewGroup` and `subViewGroup`. The subviewgroup contains views. Im adding my superviewgroup to a linearLayout and the `subViewGroups` to my `superviewgroup`.

The superviewgroup `onMeasure()` is getting called but not in the subviewgroup. but in both cases `onLayout()` method is getting called.

The code as follows

```
public class SuperViewGroup extends ViewGroup{

    public SuperViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.i("boxchart","INSIDE ON MEASURE SUPER VIEWGROUP");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        final int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                child.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            }
        }


    }


}


public class SubViewGroup extends ViewGroup{

    public SubViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.i("boxchart","INSIDE ON MEASURE SUB VIEWGROUP");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

        final int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                child.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comments are appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have to actually pass the measure to the children views:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    Log.i("boxchart","INSIDE ON MEASURE SUPER VIEWGROUP");
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            //Make or work out measurements for children here (MeasureSpec.make...)
            measureChild (child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you never actually measure your children. It is up to you to decide how to do this. Just because your `SuperViewGroup` is in a linear layout, your `SuperViewGroup` takes on responsibility to measure its children.